# How to offset lines in a radial plot?

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

I used the `radial.plot` function from the `plotrix` package to create a graph illustrating how well a sample fits into a number of different categories. The result for the example given below looks like this:

[image]

As can be seen I am already using transparency to make overlapping lines visible such as for samples 1 and 2. I still think this is a bit of an ugly workaround. What I would like to do is offset the lines slightly from each other as in this mock up:

[image]
I didn't find an answer so far. Any help?

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotrix)
library(scales)

m <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
m[1,1] <- 10
m[2,1] <- 12
m[5,2] <- 15
m[2,3] <- 20
m[4,4] <- 12
m[3,5] <- 17

colors <- brewer.pal(nrow(m), "Dark2")
pdf(file = "overview-plot.pdf", width = 14, height = 10)
par(cex.axis=2)
radial.plot(m, 
            labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
            radlab = FALSE,
            mar = c(11,8,11,8),
            cex = 2,
            label.prop = 1.3,
            rp.type="rs",
            lty = 1,
            lwd = 5, 
            start = 0.65, 
            show.grid.labels=0, 
            point.symbols=19, 
            point.col=alpha(colors, 0.8), 
            line.col=alpha(colors, 0.5),
            boxed.radial = FALSE,
            show.radial.grid = FALSE,
            radial.lim=c(0,max(m)),
            grid.bg = "#f0f0f0")
legend(
  24,8,
  c(1:5),
  col=colors,
  lty=1, 
  lwd=5, 
  bty = "n",
  title = "Samples",
  cex = 2)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should generate a plot similar to what you want. It converts the matrix into a vector of lengths and specifies the angle for each plotted length. The angles are adjusted based on the number of lengths plotted for group ("A", "B",...). Zero lengths are not plotted. The section of added or modified code is marked.

[image]
    library(RColorBrewer)
    library(plotrix)
    library(scales)

```
m <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
m[1,1] <- 10
m[2,1] <- 12
m[5,2] <- 15
m[2,3] <- 20
m[4,4] <- 12
m[3,5] <- 17

#### added code ####
# vector of number of non-zero (plotted) lines for each group (label)
num_non_zero <- colSums(m > 0)

# angles of groups (in radians)
ang_gp <- 2*pi*seq(0,length(num_non_zero)-1,1)/length(num_non_zero)

# adjustment to angles for multiple entries in groups (in radians)
# increasing values will give more space
# no check for angle being too large and being plotted in another group
ang_adj <- 2*pi/50

# plotting angles used with one entry per line plotted (in radians)
ang_plot <- rep(0,sum(num_non_zero))

# values of lengths to plot
# which() returns values with numbering starting
# going down column 1
lens_plot <- m[which(m > 0)]

# counter used in loop
counter <- 1

# colors used in plotting as index of vectors
# modulo operator returns 0 when divisible by number of groups
# so assign this to the number of groups in this case
col_plot_inds <- which(m>0)%%nrow(m)
col_plot_inds[col_plot_inds == 0] <- nrow(m)

# calcuations of adjustment to angles for each line
# based on the number of groups
# loop over the number of groups
for(i in 1:length(num_non_zero)){

  # set of angle shifts, but not demeaned
  shifts_unscaled <- ang_adj*seq(0,num_non_zero[i]-1,1)

  # shifts demeaned
  shifts_scaled <- shifts_unscaled - mean(shifts_unscaled)

  # loop over the number if elements in each group
  for(j in 1:num_non_zero[i]){

    # assigning angle as group angle plus shift
    ang_plot[counter] <-ang_plot[counter]+ ang_gp[i] + shifts_scaled[j]

    # incrementing counter
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}


colors <- brewer.pal(nrow(m), "Dark2")
pdf(file = "overview-plot.pdf", width = 14, height = 10)
par(cex.axis=2)
radial.plot(lens_plot, # using vector not matrix of value
            radial.pos=ang_plot, #  calcuated in loop
            labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
            radlab = FALSE,
            mar = c(11,8,11,8),
            cex = 2,
            label.prop = 1.3,
            rp.type="rs",
            lty = 1,
            lwd = 5, 
            start = 0.65, 
            show.grid.labels=0, 
            point.symbols=19, 
            point.col=alpha(colors[col_plot_inds], 0.8), # calling group index for colors
            line.col=alpha(colors[col_plot_inds], 0.5), # calling group index for colors
            boxed.radial = FALSE,
            show.radial.grid = FALSE,
            radial.lim=c(0,max(m)),
            grid.bg = "#f0f0f0",
            )

#### end of added code ####
legend(
  24,8,
  c(1:5),
  col=colors,
  lty=1, 
  lwd=5, 
  bty = "n",
  title = "Samples",
  cex = 2)
dev.off()
```